# LateInitializationError: Field 'controller' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, initialization

Im using a `SideBar()` widget inside the `SideBarWidget()` and using it in my main screen `SideBarScreen()`
but i cant initialize the `controller` in the `Sidebar()` widget... How can i fix this

**sidebar_Screen**

```
class _SideBarScreenState extends State<SideBarScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ScaffoldScreen(
            iconButton: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {SideBarWidget().toggle();},
              icon: kScaffoldScreenButtonIcon,
            ),
          ),
          SideBarWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**sideBarWidget**

```
class SideBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SideBarWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void toggle() {
    SideBarState().toggle();
  }

  late final SideBar sideBarWidget = SideBar();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return sideBarWidget;
  }
}
```

**SideBar**

```
class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {}

class SideBarState extends State<SideBar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  late AnimationController controller;
  late Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const  Duration(seconds: 2));

    _offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(-1.0, 0.0),
      end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeOut));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void toggle() {
    if (controller.isCompleted) {
      controller.reverse();
    }
    else {controller.forward();}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition();
  }
}
```

This gives the error *LateInitializationError: Field 'controller' has not been initialized.*

I tried passing the `controller` as a parameter to the `SideBar()` but it gives off an exception:
*This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).*

Comment: how do you call toggle inside SideBarWidget class ?

Comment: @eamirho3ein i use `SideBarState().toggle();` i can use that cuz the state of the `SIdeBar` is not private

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance of `SideBar` every time you call `SideBarWidget().toggle()`. Instead, you should be using the same instance of `SideBar` so that the state is retained.

```
class SideBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SideBarWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final sideBar = SideBar();

  void toggle() {
    sideBar.state.toggle();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return sideBar;
  }
}
```

So now you are using the same instance of `SideBar` every time and you don't need to pass any parameters.

---

Note:

To use like this, you also need to change the `SideBar` class to a `StatefulWidget`

```
class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();
}
```

Comment: i cannot get the `.state` mehtod... :(

Comment: You need to convert the Sidebar class to statefull

Comment: @PulinaHansana I have edited my answer ,look at it and @override the `createState` method

Comment: The `SideBar` class is stateful.. but the state of it is not private. It doesn't affect, right?

Comment: Have you overridden the createState

Comment: nope i havent  overridden it

Comment: For you to get the state you have it override it . else how will you get the state !!!

Comment: omg sorry i read it wrong and yes i have overridden it..

Comment: isn't it not solving your issue, try to do everything i have posted in my answer, and tell me what's not working and what error you are getting